# How to plot from variables in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to write a for loop to display a plot of the variables I have, but it's still not resolved.

I have a variable for the purpose of making a plot.

```
clear;
clc;

F = 1;
M1 = 1;
M2 = 1.5;
B = 0.1;
K1 = 0.2;
K2 = 0.15;
C1 = [B / M1 - B / M2 B / M2];
C2 = [(K1 + K2) / M1 - K1 / M1; - K2 / M2 K2 / M2];
Y = [0.1; 0.1];
dY = [0; 0];
t = 0;
dt = 0.1;
```

The plot I want to show is like this.
[image]

What do I need to add to be able to display the plot?

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please [take a tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the key is to do your own research before writing questions to stack overflow, then mentioning what you have tried to achieve that and how it failed, if you wrote that question in your url bar instead of a question you would've gotten your answer already.

Comment: you have to solve your system of differential equations and plot it. You can either solve it with the [ode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html) functions or use the [control system toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/getting-started-with-control-system-toolbox.html) to create your dynamic model and simulate it.